# WSPBuilder quick copy to bin

Tags: wspbuilder, 2007, gac

I've been developing a web part and making use of WSPBuilder's handy 'Copy to GAC' menu option to redeploy the corresponding DLL when I make a change.  This is nice and speedy so I don't have to do a full redeploy of the .wsp solution.

Now I want to actually deploy this web part so the DLL gets deployed to the web app's `bin` directory.  That's fine -- I've changed the WSPBuilder `DeploymentTarget` setting to `BIN`, and it installs to the correct place when I deploy the wsp solution.  But I'd like a quick way to copy the DLL to the correct `bin` dir whilst I'm developing.

I guess I could add a post-build xcopy to copy it to the right place.  Is that the most sensible way?  Is the reason there's a 'Copy to GAC' option but no 'Copy to bin' because it's really simple to copy to bin, and ever-so-slightly more complicated to GAC the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bin folder is web application-specific. So how would WSPBuilder know which web app's bin you want to put the DLL? That's there reason it's not there (I assume).

Comment: Ah, of course!  Didn't think of that...